# how to add single quotes and double quotes string in HTML5 data attributes

Tags: javascript, html

I need to append string something like this `{"Key": "Value"}` is got from API response which needs to be added to HTML data-attribute.

**Problem:** HTML parser changes single quote string to double quotes and ignore rest of the string. Display rest of the string in the HTML attribute color.

```
var baseDiv = $('#base');
var action = '{"key1": "Let's give a value to it "}';
var targetDiv = "<a href="javascript:void(0);"  data-action=\'' + JSON.stringify(action) + '\'></a>"
baseDiv.append(targetDiv);
```

Comment: Try `'<a ... ' + JSON.stringify(...) + '>'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var baseDiv = $('#base'); 
var action = '{"key1": "Let\'s give a value to it "}'; 
var targetDiv = '<a href="javascript:void(0);" data-action="' + JSON.stringify(action) + '"></a>' 
baseDiv.append(targetDiv);
```

> And with JQuery this is better:

```
var baseDiv = $('#base'); 
var action = '{"key1": "Let\'s give a value to it "}'; 
var targetDiv = $('<a href="javascript:void(0);">asdasd</a>');
targetDiv.attr('data-action', action);
baseDiv.append(targetDiv);
```

Answer (score 1):

This has nothing to do with HTML5, you are a little lost with string sequences, probably this is what you need:

```
var targetDiv = '<a href="javascript:void(0);"  data-action="' + JSON.stringify(action) + '"></a>';
```